# How can I make my VBA A* Pathfinding algorithm return a diagonal path?

Tags: vba, algorithm, path-finding

I am using the code here: https://www.get-digital-help.com/2014/06/16/a-quicker-a-pathfinding-algorithm/

It uses an A* Pathfinding algorithm, with a Manhattan heuristic and a 4-way grid (i.e. you can only move up, down, left and right, and not diagonally). This works well and results (when there are no obstacles) in a path that is an "L" shape:

[Current Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXDDv.png)

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[Desired Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXuLE.png)

i.e. I DON'T want to allow the path to take diagonals, but I want it to 'zigzag' such that it effectively mimics the diagonal. The length of the path is the same, but it looks like a more natural path.

How can I adjust the code to achieve this? I've fiddled around a fair bit but no joy.

Comment: If you want to prefer certain types of paths, then you have to factor that into the cost or the heuristic.  Using Euclidean distance for the heuristic prefers paths around the straight line.  The specific result you're asking for is strange, though.  I don't know how you'd get that, or even what you really want.

Comment: What you could do is using a node system, as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rop0W4QDOUI

But what you do is instead of vertical or horizontal lines you allow nodes to draw lines between them that are not vertical or horizontal. but still with the requirement that no walls are allowed between nodes. then you can draw lines between nodes to make it look like zigzaggin

Answer (score 1):

You need the under-estimating heuristic to prefer the zig-zag step.

So if you use euclidean distance for under-estimating heuristic you should get something like:

```
xxxxxxx
      xx 
       xx
        xx
         xx
```

If you want something more like

```
xxx 
  xxx
    xxx
      xxx
        xxx
```

It'll be hard (maybe impossible?) to do so by simply using A*-search on a grid.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried using the euclidean heuristic (line of code used below) but it results in the same L-shape.

H(tr, tc) = Sqr(((tr - E(0)) * (tr - E(0))) + ((tc - E(1)) * (tc - E(1))))

Comment: @J. Thompson: Than you should start to debug, because every step to the right after the goal is in a 45° angle below it the sum of "so far invested costs"+"cost of the next step"+H(tr, tc) is the lowest if you step down and not further to the right.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by adjusting the H value for each cell with the following code, which works out if there is further to go vertically or horizontally, and then slightly adjusts the H value to favour whichever cell is going in the prevailing direction (where cr and cc are the row and column values of the cell we're currently considering the neighbours of):

```
                                If Abs(cr - E(0)) > Abs(cc - E(1)) Then PreferRChange = True Else PreferRChange = False
                            If PreferRChange = True Then
                                If cr - E(0) > 0 And j = 0 Then H(tr, tc) = H(tr, tc) * 0.95
                                If cr - E(0) < 0 And j = 1 Then H(tr, tc) = H(tr, tc) * 0.95
                            Else
                                If cc - E(1) > 0 And j = 2 Then H(tr, tc) = H(tr, tc) * 0.95
                                If cc - E(1) < 0 And j = 3 Then H(tr, tc) = H(tr, tc) * 0.95
                            End If
```